# Android package com.google.android.gms.plus not available

Tags: android, google-api-client, google-plus-signin

I am trying to integrate Google+ Login for my App.  I followed the steps on this link https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating.

I run into a problem when I call `Plus.API` in the code below

```
// Build GoogleApiClient with access to basic profile
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(Plus.API)
        .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
        .build();
```

It doesn't recognize `Plus`.  The package should be `com.google.android.gms.plus`, but it isn't there.  I've tried changing the google services version, rebuilding, cleaning, deleting .iml file. I got a new .json configuration file.  Just at a stand still of what to do. Obviously, I am doing something wrong, but no clue where to begin.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what version of play services you are using

Comment: upgrade your android support respositry

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I did need to upgrade, but then I noticed I had copied a gcm dependency instead of plus.  So it pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you followed to this part in integrating manual?
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

---

Add the Google Services plugin

The Google Services plugin for Gradle parses configuration information from the google-services.json file. Add the plugin to your project by updating your top-level build.gradle and your app-level build.gradle files as follows:

Add the dependency to your project's top-level build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
```

Add the plugin to your app-level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I did follow this part.  I figured it out though,  accidentally overwrote plus dependency with gcm.  Copy paste can be an enemy sometimes. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
```